# How to configure SVN/SSH with SSH on non standard port?

Tags: ssh, tcp, subversion

I have configured SSH to be on port 20000. When I try:

```
svn co svn+ssh://server.com:20000/home/svn/proj1 proj1 --username jm
```

I get

> `svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option
>
>   from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration
>
>   file. svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly`

I think I need to tell SVN to use port 20000 also?

I am on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can define a new 'tunnel' in your Subversion configuration (`~/.subversion/config`). Find the section `[tunnels]` there and define something like:

```
[tunnels]
foo = ssh -p 20000
```

Afterwards you can contact your repository via the URL `svn+foo://server.com/home/svn/proj1 proj1`.

Comment: Also, if you want to override the default `svn+ssh` protocol's port, just define `ssh = ssh -p 20000`. This assumes you've modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server so that `Port 22` is replaced with `Port 20000`.

Comment: @Dogbert: it doesn't work like you say: I tried `ssh = ssh -p 20000` and then tried to checkout `svn+ssh://example.org/var/svn-repos/mydev/trunk` but this still tries on port 22

Answer (score 14):

Whenever you need to access an ssh server on a non-default port or with a different user name, you can define an alias in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).

```
Host mysvn
HostName server.com
Port 20000
User jm
```

Then run `svn co svn+ssh://mysvn/home/svn/proj1`.

Answer (score 6):

If for some reason you could not edit the `~/.subversion/config` file, then you can specify the port in the command-line:

`svn co svn+ssh://joe@myserver/myrepo/ --config-option="config:tunnels:ssh=ssh -p 20000"`

but you must do this option every time you run the `svn` command. This might make sense for a build agent.

Answer (score 1):

In case your ~/.subversion/config file *does not* have ssh tunnel defined, you can override ssh command on per-call basis using SVN_SSH environment variable

```
SVN_SSH='ssh -p 20000' svn co svn+ssh://server.com/home/svn/proj1 proj1 --username jm
```

For example

```
deo@fox:~$ SVN_SSH='ssh -v -p 20000' svn ls svn+ssh://svn/
OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to svn [192.168.177.2] port 20000.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.177.2 port 20000: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host svn port 20000: Connection refused
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://svn'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

This won't work if your ~/.subversion/config file *does* define ssh tunnel, in that case config file takes precedence. (Which is rather unusual. Normally it's other way around, environment variables usually take precedence over config files)